# Extrema of $f(x,y)=e^{x(y+1)}$ for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

How can I determine the extrema (minima and maxima) of $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x,y)=e^{x(y+1)}$$

for $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le 1\}?$

The solution should be $\Big(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\Big)$ for the maximum and $\Big(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\Big)$ for the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

1. Solve $f_x = 0 = f_y$ to find the local extrema, you are only interested in the ones inside $D$. You can use the 2nd derivative test to classify them.
2. Use Lagrange multipliers to solve the boundary problem looking for extreme values on $D$ itself.

Comment: When I try to solve $f_x=0=f_y$ I end up with $x=0$ and $y=-1$

Comment: @user571741 correct, nothing wrong with that. How about solving problem (2), and getting both minimum and maximum from it, and comparing to the value you got from here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a different way to do it than what you might be expected to do:

To maximize $e^{x(y+1)}$ we just have to maximize $x(y+1)$. Our domain is a a disk of radius $1$ centered at the origin; however, we can tell that the maximum will occur on the border rather than inside. Why? Let $O$ be the origin. For any point $P(x, y)$ inside the disk, if we continue along the ray OP until it hits the border, we will have both a larger $x$ and a larger $y$, so a larger $x(y+1)$. Thus we know that $x^2+y^2=1$, rather than $\le 1$.

Thus $y = \pm \sqrt {1-x^2}$, and we want to maximize $x(y+1)$ which is $x(\pm \sqrt {1-x^2}+1)$, which can be done with Calculus 1.

Comment: OP needs the minimum too